# plyr-react event callbacks not working at all

Tags: reactjs

The event callbacks in plyr-react is not working.

```
import "./styles.css";
import Plyr from "plyr-react"
import "plyr-react/plyr.css"

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Plyr 
    type="youtube" 
    videoId="umldliRDefQ"
    onPlay={()=>console.log('playing')}
    onClick={()=>{console.log('clicking')}}
    />
  );
}
```

Here is a link of a sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-morning-b1mk1t?file=/src/App.js:0-237

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try with useRef

```
const ref= useRef<APITypes | null>(null);

const plyrProps: PlyrProps = {
  source: {
    type: "video",
    title: "Example title",
    sources: [
      {
        src: "your video source",
        type: "video/webm",
        size: 1080,
      },
    ],
      poster:  "poster url if any",
    },  
  options: {
    volume: 0.3,
    controls: ["play-large"],
    hideControls: true,
  }, // OPTIONAL
};

const onPlayClick = () => {
  if (!ref|| !ref.current || !ref.current.plyr) return;
  ref.current.plyr.play();
} 

<Plyr {...plyrProps2State} ref={audioPlayer} />
```

call **onPlayClick** where you need.